# Spring Boot 2 - Only a part of output parameter is fetched by hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, sql-server-2008

I have a MS SQL stored procedure that returns html content, but when i run the stored procedure using hibernate it is not fetching full data from the output parameter, `ResultText`. This is how I am calling the stored procedure

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("Sp_Tab_PrintInvoice");
    
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("Invno", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("Ccode", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("UserName", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("Result", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("ResultText", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

query.setParameter("Invno", invoiceDto.invoiceNumber);
query.setParameter("Ccode", invoiceDto.cCode);
query.setParameter("UserName", invoiceDto.userName);
query.execute();

String message = (String) query.getOutputParameterValue("ResultText");
System.out.println(message);
```

The data type of ResultText is nvarchar(max) in the procedure.

When I run the procedure from IntelliJ Idea, it is returning full data.

Am I missing some configuration? What should I do to get full data in the output parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a lot of stepping through the debugger i found that hibernate declared the parameter as `nvarchar(4000)` for `ResultText` because i have mapped it as

`query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("ResultText", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);`

for big texts there is, `NTextType` which will not truncate the text at 4000 characters. I changed to

`query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("ResultText", NTextType.class, ParameterMode.OUT);`

and hibernate declared the parameter as `nvarchar(max)`

and the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Please if you have mentioned the size of the field in hibernate configurations , that might be one of the possible reasons for this behavior.

Comment: I haven't mentioned the size? How to configure hibernate to fetch all data?